# Lightinject with Web API - How can I get the HttpRequestMessage?

Tags: ioc-container, light-inject

How can I get the current HttpRequestMessage when using Lightinject with Web API?
In Simple Injector, for example, I have the following extension method on the container:

```
var msg = container.GetCurrentHttpRequestMessage()
```

But I couldn't find a matching one in Lightinject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look in the [Simple Injector Web API integration source code](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/tree/master/SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi), you'll find that the implementation is actually really straightforward. You can easily implement this yourself.

What you need is to create a custom `DelegatingHandler` that stores the current `HttpRequestMessage` in a way that you can retrieve it later on, as follows:

```cs
public sealed class HttpRequestMessageDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler {
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        CurrentMessage = request;
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    public static HttpRequestMessage CurrentMessage {
        get { return (HttpRequestMessage)CallContext.LogicalGetData("RequestMessage"); }
        private set { CallContext.LogicalSetData(value, "RequestMessage"); }
    }
}

// Register this handler as follows in Web API
configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new HttpRequestMessageDelegatingHandler());
```

Now you can retrieve the request's current message as follows:

```cs
HttpRequestMessageDelegatingHandler.CurrentMessage
```

The Simple Injector [documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webapiintegration.html) advises to hide this call behind a custom abstraction, such as a simple `IRequestMessageProvider`. An implementation is of course easily created:

```cs
private sealed class RequestMessageProvider : IRequestMessageProvider {
    public HttpRequestMessage CurrentMessage {
        get { return HttpRequestMessageDelegatingHandler.CurrentMessage; }
    }
}
```

Instead of creating an `IRequestMessageProvider` abstraction plus implementation, you can register it directly as delegate as follows:

```
container.Register<Func<HttpRequestMessage>>(_ =>
    () => HttpRequestMessageDelegatingHandler.CurrentMessage);
```

My preference is to use an interface instead of a `Func<T>`, because such interface is much more explicit and readable.

Comment: Thank you. And it also appears in the official docs: http://seesharper.github.io/LightInject/#webapi

Comment: @YaronLevi: It's unclear to me what `LogicalThreadStorage<T>` is. If this uses thread-local storage, the solution is incorrect, because Web API is asynchronous and moves from thread to thread. Also, instead of injecting a `Func<T>`, consider using the more specific `IRequestMessageProvider` interface as I suggested.

Comment: LogicalThreadStorage<T> is to .net 4.5 what new AsyncLocal<T> is to .net 4.6. It stores a value per logical thread of execution meaning that it flows across async points. Again, Steven, thanks for taking the time to answer :)

Comment: Hi @seesharper: This `LogicalThreadStorage<T>` is some type defined by LightInject? Can't find it in the .NET framework nor online. `AsyncLocal<T>` is defined in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll`. Is that DLL part of the standard .NET redistributable?

Comment: The LogicalThreadStorage<T> is a class that is defined by LightInject. In .Net 4.6 and the new CoreCLR there is a new class, AsyncLocal<T> that basically serves the same purpose of storing a value across async points.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @seesharper: Ah, I see (sharper) :-). They moved this type from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading to System.Threading in 4.6. The reason you define your own is because LightInject is depending on .NET 4.0 or .NET 4.5 I assume?

Comment: Exactly, in fact, LightInject only supports LogicalThreadStorage<T> on .net 4.5 as there are some issues with the CallContext on .net. 4.0.
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html.